# How to use __get magic method to get values from nested arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, getter-setter

I need to get the value of an array nested in others array from an object. Something like this:

```
$callback = $this->__get("tasks[$taskIndex]['subtasks'][$key]['callback']");
```

It don't work, as PHP thinks that the property name includes the square brackets and PHP don't interpret it as an array.

BACKGROUND

It is from the TaskRunner class that I created to help me deal with callbacks.

```
class TaskRunner(
 #code ..
 public function __get($property) {
   if(isset($this->{$property})) {
     return $this->{$property};
   }
   return null;
 }

 public function runSubtask($taskIndex, $whenToRunSubtask) {
    $subtasks = $this->__get("tasks[$taskIndex]['subtasks']");
    foreach($subtasks as $key => $subtask) {
       if($subtask['when'] === $whenToRunSubtask) {
         $callback = $this->__get("tasks[$taskIndex]['subtasks'][$key]['callback']");
         $args = $this->__get("tasks[$taskIndex]['subtasks'][$key]['args']");
         $this->runCallback($callback, $args);
      }
    }
 }

)
```

I did my work and searched for this. I found the following similar questions on StackOverflow:

[Multidimensional arrays in class with __set and __get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238470/multidimensional-arrays-in-class-with-set-and-get)

[PHP set magic method with array as names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500148/php-set-magic-method-with-array-as-names)

[Magic method get and set values dynamically from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731839/magic-method-get-and-set-values-dynamically-from-array)

This is just to name a few because I spent over 1 hour searching for a solution. So, please don't mark it as duplicated because the other questions that are similar to mine don't solve my problem.

One solution I found by myself was to use `isset`

```
$callback = isset($this->tasks[$taskIndex]['subtasks'][$key]['callback']) ? $this->tasks[$taskIndex]['subtasks'][$key]['callback'] : null;

$args = isset($this->tasks[$taskIndex]['subtasks'][$key]['args']) ? $this->tasks[$taskIndex]['subtasks'][$key]['args'] : null;
```

Although the code above works, it is pretty ugly! I'm looking for a shorter and cleaner solution. It matters because I'm using the solution above in a lot of places, so my code is difficult to read and to maintain.

I'd like to know if there is a simple, preferably built-in, way to accomplish this.

An important point is that some of the properties I'm trying to access, the `args` for example, may not exist. If they don't exist, it should return null. For example, if `$this->tasks[$taskIndex]['subtasks']['key]['args']` don't exist then the var `$args` should be `null`. The same for other variables. I need them to be `null` and not `false` because the method `runCallback` of my taskRunner class checks if the `args` is null before run the `callback`; if `args` is nulll it just run the `callback`; if not, it runs the `callback` and pass the `args` as the argument of the `callback`.

Note: PHP version is 7.3

Comment: Had you considered adding a new method with clear arguments to get what you need? In other words why do you _need_ magic for this?

Comment: Yes, I can use a new method.  Do you have any suggestions to implement the method? If so, feel free to share; I'll be glad to hear from you:)  .  One point I need to make is that it is possible that the properties I trying to access don't exist. If they don't exist, I should get null from these properties or on the contrary, it will mess other methods of the taskRunner Class.

Answer (score 1):

So I feel there are two issues here:

1. your API is kind of bulky because you are trying to wrangle this into magic
2. your sanity checks are bulky because your arrays are complex

I would refine both into a dedicated method along these lines, using clear arguments and null coalescing operator for the check:

```php
    public function callback( $index, $key ) {
        return $this->tasks[ $index ]['subtasks'][ $key ]['callback'] ?? null;
    }
```

Comment: It wasn't what I was looking for initially, but it is a much cleaner solution! Good idea! I'll implement it.

Comment: By the way, I'm not working with API; it is just for a personal website.

Comment: By API here I just mean how your methods are designed, not in a sense of any remote/network API. :)